# Invalid property id

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have one problem when I insert array in javascript function and when I click link in javascript error console write this: Invalid propery id. That is my code:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="test(<?php echo json_encode($myArray); ?>)">test</a>
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this problem?

Test function:

```
function (arr) {
    var jArray = arr;
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        document.write(jArray[i]['message'] + "<br/>");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you also post the test() function.

Comment: Can you post the code of the `test` function?

Comment: I think you need to have href as javascript:void(0)

Comment: That is my test function: function test(arr) { var jArray = arr; for(var i=0;i<4;i++) { document.write(jArray[i]['message']+"<br/>"); } }

Comment: Hint: In JSON, properties and keys are quoted with double quotes. HTML attribute values are enclosed within `"` as well, which may interfere with the JSON output. Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars/) to replace all `"` with `&quot;` before outputting: `<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($myArray)); ?>`

Comment: What is actually `echo`d to the page? What appears inside the `test(...)` onclick parameter?

Comment: Row W thanks with htmlspecialchars work, but why when I click link page is reload?

Answer (score 0):

Does `$myArray` contain string data? If so, the `json_encode` function, while not context sensitive, prints the double quotation mark, which ends the `onclick` attribute value.
You can fix it either by using single quotes instead of double for the `onclick` value or (better solution) use PHP function `htmlspecialchars`.

`<a href="javascript:;" onclick="test(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($myArray)); ?>)">test</a>`

Comment: Why when I click link page is reload?

Comment: Is it really a reload what's bothering you? IMO the problem is in your `test` function - you're using `document.write`, which, if called after the document is already fully loaded, rewrites its contents. For testing, use `console.log(data)`, which prints `data` into console (in Chrome F12 or right click -> Inspect Element -> "Console" tab). Or use `alert(data)`, or if you need them to be written into the page, use something like `document.getElementById("idOfTheElementYouWantTheDataToPrintTo").innerHTML += (jArray[i]['message'] + '<br>');`